CP-SAT solver stopped without print status statistics after first solution after implemented callback
Please, cp-sat solver stopped just after first solution when i add the test on objective value. Here below the code of callback.
class SolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):

"""Print intermediate solutions."""
def __init__(self, nb_solution_limit: int, preced_objective_value:int, limit_test_objective:int) -> None:
    cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
    self.__solution_count = 0
    self.__solution_limit = nb_solution_limit
    self._preced_objective_balue = preced_objective_value
    self._limit_test_objective = limit_test_objective

def on_solution_callback(self) -> None:
    self.__solution_count += 1
    """Called at each new solution."""
    print(f"Solution {self.__solution_count}, time = {self.wall_time} s," f" objective = {self.objective_value}")
    if self.__solution_count >= self.__solution_limit:
        print(f"stop search after {self.__solution_limit} solutions")
        self.stop_search()
    
    """If objective value of current solution i near preced solution, stop search"""
    if self._preced_objective_value > 0:
        test_propor_value =  100.0*abs(self.objective_value - self._preced_objective_value)/self.objective_value
        if test_propor_value <= self._limit_test_objective:
            self.stop_search()

It seem that the last condition is responsable.

most likely you call StopSearch()

Thanks Laurent, when the solver apply StocpSearch(), it print status statistics. But in this case, nothing. Even when i just put  if self._preced_objective_value - self.objective_value > 0: i have the same problem.
Now i passed obj = self.objective_value, and then test if self._preced_objective_value >= obj. I worked.

_preced_objective_balue is not _preced_objective_value
